# How does set::erase() behave for set::end as its argument?

Tags: c++, stl, segmentation-fault, set

suppose that we have this piece of code:

```
set<int> s;
set<int>::iterator it = s.find(val);
s.erase(it);
```

As cplusplus.com said, if `int val` doesn't exist in `set<int> s` then, `s.find(val)` will return `set::end`.

Now my question is that what will be happened if we pass `set::end` to the `set::erase()`?

Is it possible to receive signals such as `segmentation fault` or `aborted` and get an run-time error? Or this special case was handled in `set`?

Comment: I believe it's undefined, you have no idea what will happen, and it can do different things even during the same run of the program.

Comment: Why not make your code simpler and just use: `s.erase(val);` (which gives defined behavior, even if `val` isn't present)?

Comment: _"If an invalid position or range is specified, it causes undefined behavior."_ [Last line](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/erase/).

Comment: Thanks! (I asked this question because I've done this foolish approach during a contest and I didn't have time to test it. Now I can just remember not to use this method, since its behavior is undefined)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C++03, the behavior of of the `std::set::erase()` that takes a single iterator is defined in Table 69, whihc has the following assumption (highlight added):

> In Table 69, X is an associative container class, a is a value of X, a_uniq is a value of X when X supports unique keys, and a_eq is a value of X when X supports multiple keys, i and j satisfy input iterator requirements and refer to elements of value_type, [i, j) is a valid range, p is a valid iterator to a, **q is a valid dereferenceable iterator to a**, [q1, q2) is a valid range in a, t is a value of X::value_type, k is a value of X::key_type and c is a value of type X::key_compare.

Table 69 says this about that `erase()` function:

> `a.erase(q)` - erases the element pointed to by `q`

In other words, the iterator must be dereferenceable. If it's not it's undefined behavior since the pre-condition wasn't held.

There's no promise given about the library behaving any particular way.  Some libraries (such as MSVC's) can include iterator debugging in certain configurations.  For example, when run in VS 2012 with a debug configuration you'll see the following:

```
---------------------------
Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library
---------------------------
Debug Assertion Failed!

Program: C:\Windows\system32\MSVCP110D.dll
File: c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xtree
Line: 1326

Expression: map/set erase iterator outside range

For information on how your program can cause an assertion
failure, see the Visual C++ documentation on asserts.

(Press Retry to debug the application)

---------------------------
Abort   Retry   Ignore   
---------------------------
```

Answer (score 4):

This is undefined behavior. I.e. it may do nothing, crash the program, etc. Don't do this, even if your implementation of stdlib "works fine".

Comment: Indeed it is undefined, but you should probably link to some docs: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/erase/#exceptions

Answer (score 2):

For the associative containers, `erase` is defined as follows:

> `a.erase(q)`
>   Return type: `iterator`
>   erases the element pointed to by `q`. Returns an iterator pointing to the element immediately following `q` prior to the element being erased. If no such element exists, returns `a.end()`.

This function is only defined in terms of `q`. `q` is described as "a valid dereferenceable
const iterator to `a`". The past-the-end iterator is not dereferenceable, so you'll get undefined behaviour.

> Is it possible to receive signals such as segmentation fault or aborted and get an run-time error?

Yes, it's possible, but you have no guarantee over what will happen at all.